# How could I do a FULL OUTER JOIN?

Tags: database

What code should I use to execute the following SQL query?

```sql
SELECT column_name(s)
  FROM table1
  FULL OUTER JOIN table2
  ON table1.column_name = table2.column_name;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Dynamically it would look like this:

```
$q = db_select('table1')
  ->fields('table1', array('column_name'));

$q->addJoin('FULL OUTER', 'table2', NULL, 'table1.column_name = table2.column_name');
```

Which will give you

```
SELECT table1.column_name AS column_name
FROM 
{table1} table1
FULL OUTER JOIN {table2} table2 ON table1.column_name = table2.column_name
```

Or you can run any SQL string with `db_query()`:

```
$sql = <<<SQL
SELECT column_name(s)
FROM table1
FULL OUTER JOIN table2
ON table1.column_name = table2.column_name;
SQL;

$result = db_query($sql);
```

Comment: what is the NULL?

Comment: It's the desired alias for the table - if it's omitted one will be generated for you

Comment: look at this thing: $type: The type of join. Typically one one of INNER, LEFT OUTER, and RIGHT OUTER. It do not have FULL OUTER

Comment: WOW also look at this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4796872/full-outer-join-in-mysql it says that in mysql we have no full outer... :'( What is going on?

Comment: That's correct, MySQL doesn't support such a join. The code above makes the necessary assumption that you're using a DBMS which _does_ support it.

Comment: with db_query() how I can add a range and a codition?

Comment: with db_query code it gives me: syntax error, unexpected end of file why this error takes place??